# Single Frame Layout MacBook

Tags: beamer, formatting, mactex, layout

I am creating a presentation via beamer however when I run the typeset the 2 slides show up side by side rather than individually on my Mac. Is there a way to prevent this please?

Comment: How are you displaying it? Does the application allow you to show a single page at a time rather than left/right pairs?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the problem depends on the pdf-viewer, hence it is off-topic here.